# 'antislamico' o 'antiislamico' o 'anti-islamico'

Tags: word-usage

Certe volte sono perplessa su come scrivere le parole precedute dal prefisso 'anti', e ciò quando la parola da precedere inizia con la 'i'.

Peraltro poi, i vocabolari spesso non aiutano perché non tutte le *antiparole* sono presenti.

Pertanto, c'è una regola generale o dipende da parola a parola?

P.e., si scrive 'antislamico' o 'antiislamico' o, magari, 'anti-islamico'?

Answer (score 5):

[Sull'uso di  **ANTI-**](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/anti_(La-grammatica-italiana)/)

Esistono in italiano due prefissi anti-.

> - 1. Il primo – dal latino ante ‘davanti, prima’ – indica anteriorità, precedenza nel tempo o nello spazio e si trova all’inizio di parole derivate dal latino
> - anticipare (dal latino ante ‘prima’ e càpere ‘prendere’)
> - antimeridiano (dal latino antemeridianum, da ante meridiem ‘prima di mezzogiorno’)
> - o di parole formate modernamente
> - antibraccio, anticamera, antidiluviano
> - 2. Il secondo, dal greco antì ‘contro’, è usato in parole composte in cui il secondo elemento può essere un sostantivo (antincendio, antiruggine), un aggettivo (antigiuridico, anticlericale), un participio presente (antiabbagliante, antiappannante) e assume diversi significati.
> - • Opposizione, avversione, antagonismo verso qualcosa
> - antipapa, antischiavista, antidemocratico
> - • Attitudine a combattere o prevenire qualcosa
> - antiallergico, antisettico, antispasmodico
> - • Capacità di evitare o impedire qualcosa
> - anticoagulante, antifurto, antisismico
> - • Contraddizione, contrasto, o anche indipendenza da qualcosa (con significato simile all’alfa privativo, ➔a-)

- antiestetico, antistorico

> - Posizione contraria, movimento in senso opposto, posizione speculare

- anticiclone, antipodi.

**DUBBI**

> - Nella scrittura, tra anti- (nel significato di ‘contro’) e il secondo elemento composto si può usare il trattino, specie quando si tratta di neologismi o di composti occasionali o rari. Il trattino viene usato con maggiore frequenza quando la parola successiva comincia per vocale: l’uso resta comunque molto oscillante, e si alterna anche alla grafia separata dei due elementi.
> - Nei giornali degli ultimi anni, tra le centinaia di nuovi prefissati con anti-, si possono trovare

- antiburqa, anti-burqa
- anti-carovita, anti carovita
- antidegrado, anti-degrado, anti degrado

> - Nei casi in cui anti- precede una parola che comincia per i, si tende a evitare la sequenza di due vocali identiche: antincendio è molto più frequente di anti-incendio o di antiincendio.

Fonte Treccani.it

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=antislamico%2Canti-islamico%2Canti%20islamico&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cantislamico%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canti%20-%20islamico%3B%2Cc0) *anti-islamico  vs antislamico*